# Enable accessibility (Voiceover, NV Access or any screen reader) in Java WebView

Tags: java, webview, accessibility, screen-readers

I have searched for similar questions and I didn't find any talking about this.

We have a JavaFX application where the main content is a WebView. We want to allow screen readers to detect and read the content, but it seems to be broken.

Screen readers like NV Access and VoiceOver detect and read the frame, buttons and everything outside the WebView but not the HTML content.

Is there any limitation that explains why screen readers can't access the web page? Is there any way to allow it?

Answer (score 0):

I've run into this same issue. I have a workaround idea that works like this:

1. On the relevant html elements that I want to read,  add an `onfocus()` handler that calls up through the JavaScript bridge and passes up the text that I want the screen reader to read to a java method e.g. `readText(text)`.
2. In `readText(text)`, create a Swing element, e.g. a `JLabel`, and add the "text" to the accessible description of the `JLabel` and then manually trigger the screen reader to read "text".

However, I can't get the "manually trigger the screen reader to read" step to work. I've been studying the Java Accessibility Utilities documentation but can't find anything that works. Does anyone know if this is possible?